# Non-ASCII characters are not loaded correctly from Apache Ant XML file

Tags: xml, unicode, ant, character-encoding

I have the following Apache Ant test file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test">
<property name="str" value="this is a test, ěščřžýáíéůú" />
<target name="test">
    <echo message="str is &quot;${str}&quot;" />
</target>
</project>
```

As you can see, the property contains some non-ASCII characters. These characters do not seem to be loaded correctly from the Apache Ant XML file. It shows only question marks `?` in both console and output file produced by `-l` switch. I have tested with *Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013* on Windows 7 with *Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)*.

What can I do about it?

Comment: What is the *actual* encoding of the file?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: The actual encoding is actually UTF-8 as far as I can determine. Both Notepad++ and jEdit agree.

Comment: Sorry, the Windows console can't Unicode for applications using the C standard library including Java.

Comment: @bobince It has the same result even when I forward it using -l to a file. And it is Java. It should handle UTF - 8 well.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is a combination of [System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) which transcodes character data to an obsolete "[ANSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964654)" encoding and *cmd.exe* which expects character data to be in an obsolete [OEM encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964655) from the DOS days. See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html) for more.

Assuming your system "[ANSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964654)" encoding supports the characters in question switch the console to use a Unicode font and use [chcp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733037.aspx) to switch to that encoding.

Comment: The problem is visible also in output file even when the relevant characters never come close to console. See my post mentioning the `-l` option.

Comment: When you open a Windows Command Prompt and type `chcp` what number is printed? Are all the characters printed as question marks or just some?